# Matlab restoring an image to its original colors

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, colors, color-management

I want to take a picture of something.

The colors in the picture are not the same as I see in my eyes.

So in order to fix this problem, I decided to place a red paper (with RGB: `[255 0 0]`) and then take a picture including this paper.

If I see that the RGB of the paper is changed (such as `[243 15 7]`),
I will change all the RGB in the picture by the next way:

- **R** (red), it will be added by value `12`.
- **G** (green), it will be subtracted by value `15`.
- **B** (blue), it will be subtracted by value `7`.

By this way, my paper will be changed to his correct RGB `[255 0 0]` and then I can be sure that all the rest picture's RGB was changed to its original color.

What do you think about this way?

Comment: Sounds like white balancing to me, might be worth a look: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_balance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called Color Management/Color Correction.

I have some remarks:

- First, you must make sure that your monitor is calibrated. If it isn't calibrated, it makes no sense to do a visual check. If you have a standard consumer monitor, chances are that you cannot calibrate it at all.
- Why do you assume that the RGB of the paper is [255,0,0]? It could be slightly greener or bluer. You should use a known target, like [Macbeth ColorChecker](http://www.ae5d.com/macbeth.html)
- The offset transformation that you are using, will not work if amount of light is changed. Instead, it should be multiplicative to be invariant to illumination intensity. Check out the standard method of color correction, [Color Correction Matrix](http://www.imatest.com/docs/colormatrix/).
- You will need more than one known color. Three is the absolute minimum to calibrate the matrix.

Comment: wow! thank you about your comment! I will try all the suggestions in this topic. thanks!!!!

Comment: ok, I read all you writed me and I have 3 known colors (I know their RGB, the seller told me).
now, I have three colors, for example: red [237 12 15], green [35 229 20] and blue [25 19 241]. now, I take a photo of them and the values was changed me to: [212 16 25], green [27 215 15] and blue [ 25 26 233]. what should I do with these changes in all the pixels of the image? thank you!

Comment: @AlonShmiel, Use the least squares method to find the best matrix.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use white paper instead of red. By doing this, you will have information about three colors, not only red. In the perfect case, RGB values for white paper will be equal, for example, you get (197,197,197). But if they are not equal, for example (190, 204, 203), you can change them for each pixel by multiplying on some number:

```
mean = (190 + 204 + 203) / 3
red_new = red * mean / 190
green_new = green * mean / 204
blue_new = blue * mean / 203
```

Comment: thank you! it sounds me good, I will try that. red, green and blue are the rgb of each pixel in the picture?

Comment: Yes, they are. By the way, this adjustment is called "color balance" or "white balance", if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I read about your suggestion and I found that the camera has a function of 'white balance', so in addition to this option, I will make a function that will include the suggestion of Andrey. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

i read about an iterative process of colour correction that could perhaps be applied in your case:

[Correction with Photoshop in 7 Easy Steps by Helen
Bradley](http://digital-photography-school.com/color-correction-photoshop),

nevertheless, confirm that it works as expected

good luck

Comment: that is entirely up to you. note that the article demonstrates this colour correction approach in photoshop, it can be implemented f.e. in matlab as well. you could compare which works better, just an idea...

Comment: I tried to understand what he wrote in his article but my english is not very well, so I let my brother to translate it tomorrow. If I understood, he did a color correction by 3 points in the picture that he knew their RGB, and by the RGB of these 3 points, he repair the picture. Thank you again! :]]